# How to build isochrones with GeoTools?

Tags: geotools, network, time, graph, isochrone

It is possible to compute shortest paths with [GeoTools](https://geotools.org/) with [its graph package](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/graph/path/package-summary.html).

Is there a package (or extension) for computing [isochrone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isochrone_map) lines or areas, that is the area which can be reached from a point in less than X minutes by travelling on a transport network ?

Answer (score 2):

Not currently, you would need to use the `gt-graph` package to compute the time taken to each node in your graph and then contour those times.

As far as I know the only contouring code in GeoTools is a process that calls JAI-Tools on a raster (coverage) as in [this demo](https://github.com/mbedward/jaitools/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/org/jaitools/demo/contour/ContourDemo.java). But there is a `DelaunayTrianglator` in the graph package that you could apply the [marching squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) algorithm to (scroll down to the triangle implementation).

If you do implement the vector algorithm we would be delighted to add the code to GeoTools.

Comment: Thanks Ian ! It looks indeed not so complicated to implement, and even fun. I keep that in mind for later...